# code for creating "if... then" statement for a range of values of two variables

Tags: r, if-statement, range

I am trying to create an "`if... then`" statement in `R` in which two variables, `G1` and `G2`, lie within a range of values in a given dataset. For example, the "if...then" scenario I would like to test is:

`if (200 > G1 > -100) and (200 > G2 > -100), then G = mean(G1,G2)`

My code for the scenario looks like this:

`if(200 > G1 > -100 & 200 > G2 > -100) {G = mean(G1,G2)}`

The error that I getting reads:

```
Error: unexpected '>' in "        if(200 > G1 >"
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

UPDATE:

G1 and G2 are two lists of values in a data frame

Here is an example:

G1 = 101, G2 = 2

Expected output: G = mean(101,2) = 51.5

Comment: are `G1` and `G2` scalar values or columns in a data frame?  can you provide example data and expected output?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @andrew_reece G1 and G2 are columns in a data frame. Here is an example: G1 = 101, G2 = 2.      Output: G = mean(101,2) = 51.5

Answer (score 1):

The `R` syntax is incorrect.  It is different from the mathematical syntax

```
if(G1 > -100 &  G1< 200 & G2 > -100 & G2 < 200) G <- mean(c(G1, G2))
```

-output

```
G
[1] 137.5
```

---

Having said that the `if/else` works only when 'G1', 'G2' are of `length` 1 and not greater than 1 as `if/else` is not vectorized i.e. if the length is more than 1, use the vectorized `ifelse` or create a logical index, subset the values of 'G1', 'G2' based on that index and get the `mean`

```
G1 <- c(125, 135, 142, 215)
G2 <- c(-123, 122, 180, 140)
i1 <- G1 > -100 &  G1< 200 & G2 > -100 & G2 < 200
 mean(c(G1[i1], G2[i1]))
[1] 144.75
```

Or if we are interested in the `mean` of corresponding elements that meet the condition, then `cbind` the objects to a `matrix`, subset the rows with 'i1' and get the `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(cbind(G1, G2)[i1,])
[1] 128.5 161.0
```

#### data

```
G1 <- 150
G2 <- 125
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your G1 and G2 in a dataframe, you can use `dplyr::mutate()` `rowMeans()` and `replace()` values in rows not meeting the conditions with NA.

```
df%>%mutate(conditioned_mean=rowMeans(.)%>%
                    replace(., !if_all(G1:G2, ~.x>-100 & .x<200), NA))

   G1   G2 conditioned_mean
1 125 -123               NA
2 135  122            128.5
3 142  180            161.0
4 215  140               NA
```

*Data*

```
G1 <- c(125, 135, 142, 215)
G2 <- c(-123, 122, 180, 140)
df<-data.frame(G1, G2)
```

Comment: Excellent. I forgot about between.